# git clone a specific release from a forked git branch

Tags: git, github, tags, git-clone, git-checkout

I want to clone a specific version of a forked git repository, but seem to be misunderstanding why I am getting what I am getting.
I want to pull v2.43.0 from https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de,

1.) which in theory should also have "hstore-only.style" (but does not if you click on v2.43.0). It seems to have it only under master. Why is that?

2.) If I do

```
$ git clone git://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de.git
```

This gives me the master, and I see all files including "hstore-only.style"

```
$ cd openstreetmap-carto-de
$ git tag -l
```

this already gives me v2.9.1, which is confusing. Because there the highest tag is 2.43.0. Where does the 2.9 come from?

3.) and with

```
$ git checkout v2.43.0
```

I would get the reduced file set without `hstore-only.style`.
Is there a way I can get the 2.43 with that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to pull v2.43.0 from https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de,

```
git clone --branch v2.43.0 --single-branch https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de
```

If the tag exists on the remote side (and [it seems it does](https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de/releases/tag/v2.43.0)), it will allow you to clone it locally.

You can add `--depth 1` if you don't want the full history locally.

A `git describe --all` will give you `v2.43.0`

However, in that branch, there is no `hstore-only.style`.

If I clone the full repo and do:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\openstreetmap-carto-de>git log --full-history --oneline --decorate -- hstore-only.style
8a386af Merge tag 'v3.1.0'
cbbe151 Merge tag 'v3.0.1'
30e20a5 Merge tag 'v3.0.0'
d876fbb Merge tag 'v2.45.1'
7dcf103 Merge tag 'v2.45.0'
ad8bd4f Merge tag 'v2.44.1' from upstream
8ac3f86 Merge upstream tag 'v2.44.0'
```

As you can see, that file was probably introduced in v2.44.0 and more, not yet in v2.43.0.

Comment: Great, so I just can use 2.45.1 (as 3 has changes from openstreetmap-carto that I do not want to implement) but how come there is anything beyond 2.43? If I click on https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de/tags, the highest one I see is 2.43  And how come `$ git tag -l` does not give me anything beyond 2.9. And does that mean 2.9 actually does not have `hstore-only.style` given that it does not show up in your `git log` call ?

Comment: @TheRealPir those tags were probably deleted.

Comment: so is there a difference between the UI of github and what I actually pull? In other words which version can I actually download? 1.) the max 2.43.0 that is shown on the github UI 2.) the 2.9.1 that I see when running `git tag -l` or 3) 3.1.0 which git log shows (but without anything between 2.45.1 and 3.0.0)? Sorry for being confused and a big thanks for your time teaching me

Comment: @TheRealPir I see all the tags when I do a `git tag -l`: same as the ones listed in https://github.com/giggls/openstreetmap-carto-de/releases

Comment: I also see additional beyond 2.43 (which is the highest I see under the mentioned link): v2.5.0
v2.6.0
v2.7.0
v2.8.0
v2.9.0
v2.9.1

Comment: so I just tested it. I can `git checkout` any version that `git tag -l` mentions (even the 2.5-2.9, but they don't have the `hstore` file), even it if is not mentioned on the github UI. I unfortunately cannot check out the versions mentioned with `git log` that include `hstore`.... feels a little chaotic

Comment: @TheRealPir Yes, those tags were deleted after being merged into `master`. Meaning `master` seems to be the only branch currently including `hstore-only.style`.